# From yml to Java CronExpression Object conversion failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron

I've just upgraded my code from java 11, spring 2.7.4 to java 17, spring 3.2.2 and now I'm facing this weird issue: my code cannot parse anymore what I've defined inside my yml configuration file to java CronExpression object, getting instead this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'recovery.cron' to org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronExpression:

    Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronExpression]

Action:

Update your application's configuration


Process finished with exit code 1
```

my yml file looks like this:

```
recovery:
  cron: '0 31 0/1 * * ?'
```

and the java class defining this configuration object is like that:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronExpression;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Validated
@Getter
@Setter
public class RecoverySettings {

    @NotNull
    private CronExpression cron;

}
```

I can't figure out what's happening different from java 11